# Comparing non-parametric correlations

Tags: correlation, paired-data, prediction-interval

I have two correlation (Spearman's rho) matrices from a single sample (before/ after intervention) and I would like to compare them to see whether intervention changed each or some of these correlations. What I have done is to calculate the prediction interval (with the predictionInterval R package)  of each correlation index in the first (before) matrix, and checked whether or not it includes the corresponding correlation index in the second (after) matrix... To me this approach makes sense, but I would like to confirm its validity (or get suggestions of a better approach)

Thanks in advance for any possible answer,